# Getting data frame using incremental data by two values in R

Tags: r

I have the following numbers

```
M<- 40
N<- 100
```

I want to generate the following table:

```
Plate   N   Yellow  Blue
Plate2  2   20  50
Plat4   4   10  25
Plate6  6   6.666666667 16.66666667
Plat8   8   5   12.5
Plate10 10  4   10
Plat12  12  3.333333333 8.333333333
```

The logic is that= M/2, M/4, M/6/ M/8, M/10, M/12. Similar to N: N/2, N/4, N/6/ N/8, N/10, N/12
This gives the table above. Is there a simple code to get it with any procedure with or without increment. For example, generating it with SQRT with a lack of increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
M <- 40
N <- 100
#Create sequence from 2 to 12 with step of 2
vec <- seq(2, 12, 2)
#Divide each value of M and N with `vec`
mat <- sapply(c(M, N),`/`, vec)
#Create a dataframe combining all the values.
data.frame(Plate = paste0('Plate', vec), N = vec, mat)

#    Plate  N    X1    X2
#1  Plate2  2 20.00 50.00
#2  Plate4  4 10.00 25.00
#3  Plate6  6  6.67 16.67
#4  Plate8  8  5.00 12.50
#5 Plate10 10  4.00 10.00
#6 Plate12 12  3.33  8.33
```

Comment: Thanks, this is too specific for this. I wanted to get a general code to work for any procedure. For example, when I use SQRT instead of / and remove vec, it gives me only M. Can we do better?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you update your post with another example?

Comment: That doesn't help. Please add an example with similar expected output.

Comment: @user330, Ronak’s answer can quite easily be modified in many different was. Just swap out the function applied  in sapply and change the input vector and parameters. If you want to fill a table you need to somehow encode the rules and input parameters.